# Dynamic properties in Sinatra::ConfigFile

Tags: ruby, sinatra, configuration-files

Is it possible to expand dynamic properties when generating settings with [Sinatra::ConfigFile](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file.html)?

Say I have this logging.yaml:

```
elasticsearch_url:
  development: "http://kibana.#{myVar}.mydomain/elasticsearch/"
  production:  "http://kibana.mydomain/elasticsearch/"

kibana_url:
  development: "http://kibana.#{myVar}.mydomain/kibana/#"
  production:  "http://kibana.mydomain/kibana/#"
```

Here's a dummy config.ru:

```
require 'sinatra/config_file'

configure do      
  set :default_dashboard, 'mydashboard'
  set :myVar, 'st'
  config_file 'instances.yaml', 'logging.yaml'
end
```

Now, when I run in "development" mode, I'd like all settings with `#{myVar}` to be expanded, e.g. `settings.kibana_url` would become  `http://kibana.st.mydomain/kibana/#`.

What is the best way to achieve this?  I could settle for a for loop through the values in the `settings` variable, if that is possible.

(Disclaimer: I'm new to Ruby, so complete examples would help a lot.)

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but if I were looking to do this, I wouldn't use the extension.  I'd have a config.rb program, put the settings in that, and load it into my config.ru with a `require`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `logging.yaml` to `logging.yaml.erb` and use `<%= settings.myVar %>` instead of `#{myVar}`.  Voila!

This is because Sinatra::ConfigFile supports both Yaml and ERB files as input.

Comment: A note of caution - this won’t work if you are using the modular style of Sinatra app, as it relies on the Erb being evaluated with the same binding as the code that calls it so that `settings` is available. This happens to be the case for classic style apps because `settings` is added to the top level in that case and the default is to use the top level binding in Erb. You could use `MyAppname.settings` in that case though. (It also looks like a fairly simple fix to ConfigFile to make this work).